Issues after upgrade Ubuntu 22.04
I just upgrade my Ubuntu 22.04 last night to the new release on September 10,2024. The issue I am having is this...

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

I have checked and tried various forum methods but non of them were helpful.
Also during the upgrade I got a lot of SyntaxWarnings...

Setting up python3-aptdaemon (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu44) ...
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/core.py:96: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '-'
REGEX_VALID_PACKAGENAME = "^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-+.]+(:[a-z0-9]+)?$"
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/core.py:99: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '-'
REGEX_VALID_VERSION = "^[0-9][0-9.+-A-Za-z:~]$"
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/core.py:101: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '-'
REGEX_VALID_RELEASE = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+$"
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/progress.py:57: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '['
REGEX_ANSI_ESCAPE_CODE = chr(27) + "[[;?0-9][A-Za-z]"
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/progress.py:667: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
match = re.match("\s*'(.)'\s'(.)'.", message_raw)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/progress.py:791: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
match = re.match("\s*'(.)'\s'(.)'.", status[3])
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/aptworker.py:462: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\S'
if re.match("(http|https|ftp)://\S+?:\S+?@\S+", uri):
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:89: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\d'
MATCH_CVE = "CVE-\d{4}-\d{4}"
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:325: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '/'
pattern = "^%s$" % filename[1:].replace("/", "/")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:327: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '/'
pattern = "/%s$" % filename
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:350: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '/'
pattern = "^%s$" % filename.replace("/", "/")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:352: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '/'
pattern = ".*/%s$" % filename
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:661: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '+'
"(?P.+) (?P[-+][0-9]+)$",

Anyone able to help me out please and thank you.

Did you upgrade from 20.04 -> 22.04 or 22.04 -> 24.04?

This question is similar to: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository ... doesn't support architecture 'i386'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
